# PDF's Vacíos con Dompdf

Tags: php, wordpress, dompdf

estoy haciendo una integración de facturas a un sitio wordpress, en el cual tengo que generar un pdf de las facturas que se timbran, por lo que tienen que hacerse varios PDF's a la vez, entonces en un ciclo foreach estoy haciendo el llamado de la clase que hice con dompdf, en mis pruebas estoy tratando de generar 9 PDF's a la vez, y los archivos se crean correctamente, pero el detalle es que solo el primer PDF tiene contenido, los otros 8 PDF's están vacíos, alguno tendrá idea de lo que pasa? Aquí dejo el código:

```
class genera_pdf{
 public function genera($path){
        $fechaHoy= date( 'Y-m-d');
        ob_start();
        require_once plugin_dir_path(__DIR__) . 'templates/pdf/factura.php';
        $codigoHTML=ob_get_clean();
        $pdf= new Dompdf();
        $pdf->load_html($codigoHTML);
        $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
        $pdf->render();
        $salida = $pdf->output();
        file_put_contents($path['basedir'].'/profact/FacturaRetenciones-'.$fechaHoy.'.pdf', $salida);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví, el problema era con la línea:

```
require_once plugin_dir_path(__DIR__) . 'templates/pdf/factura.php';
```

Ya que require_once, incluye el archivo solo si no se incluyó antes, como en la primera recorrida del ciclo ya se había incluido, las siguientes ya no lo hacía y como se guardaba todo en el búffer con ob_get_clean(), a la vez se borra al terminar, por eso quedaba completamente en blanco, lo único que hice fue cambiar a:

```
include(plugin_dir_path(__DIR__) . 'templates/pdf/factura.php');
```

Con eso se resolvió mi problema y ya todos los PDF's tienen el contenido que quería